# ZuneHD not being seen on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I recently upgraded to Windows 7, possibly the worst choice I have ever made.  Immediately after updating, I attempted to connect my Zune to my PC, assuming that a Microsoft device should work on a Microsoft system.  Windows guided me to install the Zune software, which took me three times to install, I finally had to run it in compatibility for windows XP.  After the software finally decided to open, I plugged my Zune into the PC, hoping  the best.  Absolutely nothing happened, other then a notification that Windows could not install my devices driver!  I uninstalled the driver, and reinstalled the driver, nothing.  I used the Microsoft "Fix-It" program, nothing *surprise*, I searched countless forums, trying a multitude of useless answers.  Please help me!!

Comment: Also, my zune is functional, it works great under Linux using Amarok, other than the inability to sync.

Comment: Please, anyone help